# Create animation with circles time dependent

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi I try to make a animation. One of the 3 circles which become drawed when the function is called should move from right to left at first one random (yellow, blue or orange) circle should become drawed on the canvas then after 3 seconds the next random circle and then after 2,8 seconds and so far. 
How can I do that? Now the circles become drawed every time again when the mainloop starts run again.

```
    window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
  var C = 1; // canvas width to viewport width ratio
  var el = document.getElementById("myCanvas");


  var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

  var canvasWidth = viewportWidth * C;
  var canvasHeight = viewportHeight;
  el.style.position = "fixed";
  el.setAttribute("width", canvasWidth);
  el.setAttribute("height", canvasHeight);
  var x = canvasWidth / 100;
  var y = canvasHeight / 100;
var ballx = canvasWidth / 100;
var n;


  window.ctx = el.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  // draw triangles


  function init() {
        ballx;      
        return setInterval(main_loop, 1000);
  }
  function drawcircle1()
  {
  var radius = x * 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ballx * 108, canvasHeight / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
      ctx.fill(); 
  }
function drawcircle2()
  {
  var radius = x * 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ballx * 108, canvasHeight / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
      ctx.fill(); 
  }
  function drawcircle3()
  {
  var radius = x * 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ballx * 105, canvasHeight / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
      ctx.fill(); 
  }

  function draw() {   
        var counterClockwise = false;

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    //first halfarc
   ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x * 80, y * 80, y * 10, 0 * Math.PI, 1 * Math.PI, counterClockwise);
    ctx.lineWidth = y * 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.stroke();

    //second halfarc
   ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x * 50, y * 80, y * 10, 0 * Math.PI, 1 * Math.PI, counterClockwise);
    ctx.lineWidth = y * 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.stroke();

    //third halfarc
   ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x * 20, y * 80, y * 10, 0 * Math.PI, 1 * Math.PI, counterClockwise);
    ctx.lineWidth = y * 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.stroke();



    // draw stop button
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x * 87, y * 2);
      ctx.lineTo(x * 87, y * 10);
      ctx.lineWidth = x;
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x * 95, y * 2);
      ctx.lineTo(x * 95, y * 10);
      ctx.lineWidth = x;
      ctx.stroke();


      function drawRandom(drawFunctions){
    //generate a random index
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * drawFunctions.length);

    //call the function
    drawFunctions[randomIndex]();
}
drawRandom([drawcircle1, drawcircle2, drawcircle3]);


  }

  function update() {
    ballx -= 0.1;


    if (ballx < 0) {
      ballx = -radius;         


    }

  }







  function main_loop() {
    draw();
    update();
    collisiondetection();

  }


  init();

            function initi() {
                console.log('init');
                // Get a reference to our touch-sensitive element
                var touchzone = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                // Add an event handler for the touchstart event
                touchzone.addEventListener("mousedown", touchHandler, false);
            }

            function touchHandler(event) {
                // Get a reference to our coordinates div
                var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                // Write the coordinates of the touch to the div
                if (event.pageX < x * 50 && event.pageY > y * 10) {
                    ballx += 1;
                } else if (event.pageX > x * 50 && event.pageY > y * 10 ) {
                    ballx -= 1;
                }

                console.log(event, x, ballx);

                draw();


            }
            initi();
            draw();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your code, but I think I understand that you want to know how to delay when each circle will start animating to the left.

**Here's how to animate your yellow, blue & orange circles with different delays:**

- Define the 3 circles using javascript objects and store all definintions in an array.
- Inside an animation loop:

  - Calculate how much time has elapsed since the animation began
  - Loop through each circle in the array
  - If a circle's delay time as elapsed, animate it leftward
- When all 3 circles have moved offscreen-left, stop the animation loop.

Here's annotated code and a Demo:

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvasWidth=canvas.width;
var canvasHeight=canvas.height;

// predifine PI*2 because it's used often
var PI2=Math.PI*2;

// startTime is used to calculate elapsed time
var startTime;

// define 3 circles in javascript objects and put
// them in the arcs[] array
var arcs=[];
addArc(canvasWidth,canvasHeight/2,20,0,PI2,0,-1,'yellow');
addArc(canvasWidth,canvasHeight/2+40,20,0,PI2,3000,-1,'blue');
addArc(canvasWidth,canvasHeight/2+80,20,0,PI2,8000,-1,'orange');

// begin animating
requestAnimationFrame(animate);


function animate(time){

  // set startTime if it isn't already set
  if(!startTime){startTime=time;}

  // calc elapsedTime
  var elapsedTime=time-startTime;

  // clear the canvas 
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);

  // assume no further animating is necessary
  // The for-loop may change the assumption 
  var continueAnimating=false;
  for(var i=0;i<arcs.length;i++){
    var arc=arcs[i];
    // update this circle & report if it wasMoved
    var wasMoved=update(arc,elapsedTime);
    // if it wasMoved, then change assumption to continueAnimating
    if(wasMoved){continueAnimating=true;}
    // draw this arc at its current position
    drawArc(arc);
  }

  // if update() reported that it moved something
  // then request another animation loop
  if(continueAnimating){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }else{
    // otherwise report the animation is complete
    alert('Animation is complete');
  }
}

function update(arc,elapsedTime){
  // has this arc's animation delay been reached by elapsedTime
  if(elapsedTime>=arc.delay){
    // is this arc still visible on the canvas
    if(arc.cx>-arc.radius){
      // if yes+yes, move this arc by the specified moveX
      arc.cx+=arc.moveX;
      // report that we moved this arc
      return(true);
    }
  }
  // report that we didn't move this arc
  return(false);
}

// create a javascript object defining this arc 
function addArc(cx,cy,radius,startAngle,endAngle,
                 animationDelay,moveByX,color){

  arcs.push({
    cx:cx,
    cy:cy,
    radius:radius,
    start:startAngle,
    end:endAngle,
    // this "delay" property is what causes this
    // circle to delay before it starts to animate
    delay:animationDelay,
    moveX:moveByX,
    color:color,
  });
}

// draw a given arc
function drawArc(a){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(a.cx,a.cy,a.radius,a.start,a.end);
  ctx.fillStyle=a.color;
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
```